# Format a cell colour based on another cell colour

Tags: java, colors, cell

I have unique situation where I have a dropdown list that has conditional formatting that when I select a contractor it also fill that cell with a particular colour. However I wanted to populate some cells in same row with a set of numbers representing resources, the issue is I wanted to be able to type in any number in this cell to represent the number of resource and this cell will inherit the colour of the cell with the contractor. 
If the contractor was ACME and the fill colour was Green I want the cells with the resource number to automatically fill as Green. 
Can this be done???

Help please

Comment: Your question is to broad. You do not express that the application you used is represent via swing or console or awk or html.

Comment: A code example will help to understand your situation better